# Why is this for each loop not being entered?

Tags: foreach, action, listener

I have similar for each loops in the same code that do the EXACT same thing, but for some reason my program never enters this one.

Any ideas off the bat?

```
JButton undo = new JButton(" Undo ");
    undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            indices = list.getSelectedIndices();
            for(int x: indices){
                                      // do stuff
                           }
                       }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Just noting that you have one too many closing brackets. I'm guessing one of them was accidentally leftover from removing the loop's inner code?

Comment: Either the undo event never happens or indices is empty.

Comment: Yes, the extra bracket was a result of me removing the inner code.

Comment: As for the undo event, it does happen, I put a a few print statements within that printed out, just nothing in the loop. 

Also, indices isn't empty, I printed out its contents as a test and it all checks out.

I'm out of ideas...

Comment: What happens if you use a normal for loop? Does it still not enter the loop? `for (int x = 0; x < indices.length; ++x) { //do stuff using indices[x] }`

Comment: That seems to have worked.